# Aggregate functions in Sparql query with empty records

Tags: sum, sparql, aggregate-functions

I've been trying to run a sparql query against https://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole# to yield some sold properties result.

The query is the following:

```
  PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
  PREFIX  ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>

  SELECT  sum(?ukhpi_salesVolume)
  WHERE
     { { SELECT  ?ukhpi_refMonth ?item
         WHERE
          { ?item  ukhpi:refRegion  <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/haringey> ;
               ukhpi:refMonth   ?ukhpi_refMonth
             FILTER ( ?ukhpi_refMonth >= "2019-03"^^xsd:gYearMonth )
             FILTER ( ?ukhpi_refMonth < "2020-03"^^xsd:gYearMonth )
           
          }
      }
      OPTIONAL
    { ?item  ukhpi:salesVolume  ?ukhpi_salesVolume }
  }
```

The problem is, the result from this is empty. However, if i run the same query without the SUM on the 4th line, i can see there are 11 integer records.

My thoughts are that there is a 12th, empty record which causes all the issues in the SUM operation, but sparql is not my storngest side so i'm not sure how to filter this (and remove any empty records) if that's really the problem.

I've also noticed that most of the aggregate functions do not work as well(min, max, avg). *Count does, and returns 11

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved this myself, all that was needed was a coalesce which apparently existed in sparql too.

So:

```
SELECT sum(COALESCE(?ukhpi_salesVolume, 0))
```

instead of just

```
SELECT sum(?ukhpi_salesVolume)
```

Comment: great. Do you also understand why you have to do this? It's basically because one value is *not bound*,  and `sum` in SPARQL is defined using XSD's `op:numeric-add` of the evaluation of the sum'ed expression over the grouped rows. If one of the expressions is an error, then the whole aggregate is an error - the "not bound" here is unfortunately an error

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. At first i couldn't see the empty record, because the "select by column" query was returning 11 plain numeric records. Once i replaced the column with *, i realized there was actually a 12th, blank record and knew that was probably the issue, even though i was hoping there could be an implemented work-around for "unbound" records(count them as 0's). Knowing some SQL, hoping there would be similarity with SPARQL i tried coalsece and got lucky